# Python Flask is showing old output

Tags: python, flask

[image]

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")

def hello_world():
  return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(debug=True)
```

Hi I am beginner in Python and I have issue with reloading Flask.
I have tried Ctrl+Shift+R (hard refresh), added debug=True. However, my output is not updated to the new one.
I have referenced from other stack overflow posts in regards with this issue but it still does not work.
Please do help, thank you!

Comment: Sounds like you haven't restarted your script after you did the changes.

Comment: @Sefan may I know how do I restarted my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maybe change the location of the  project VSC sometimes make cache files that cause this issue *JUST CANGE THE LOCATION OF PROJECT SAVED* **also** *use code instead of image it helps clone the problem :)*